# Java sychronized block while access to the class A field in class B

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

I want to ask question connected with synchronization in Java and to clarify my doubts I wrote simple code as follows:

```
class A {
 public int variable;
 public int secondVariable;
 public Object variableLock = new Object();
 public Object secondVariableLock = new Object();

 public void doingSthWithVariable() {
  synchronized (variableLock) {
  .... } } 

 public void doingSthWithVariableInOtherMethod() {
  synchronized (variableLock) {
  .... } }

 public void doingSthWithSecondVariable() {
  synchronized (secondVariableLock) {
  .... } }

 public void doingSthWithSecondVariableInOtherMethod() {
  synchronized (secondVariableLock) {
  .... } }

}

class B {
 public A instanceOfA;

 public void doingSthWithAVariables() {
  synchronized (instanceofA.variableLock) {
    synchronized (instanceofA.secondVariableLock) {
      ....} } }
 }
```

My question is: if it's safe and is it a good practice to use variableLock/secondVariableLock from class A in class B? 
I mean, I need to block any change of these two variables in instance of class B and I'm wondering if it's a good way to do it. 
And another question: what if I have the same instanceOfA in more than one B objects?

It seems to me like answer is yes (it's not unsafe), but I just want to ensure and ask about better ways to do it.

Comment: Using public mutable locks is definitely not a good idea. I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but encapsulation is the key to make things safe. If you want a method to be executed in a mutex with both variable and second variable, put it in class A. Make your locks private and final.

Comment: and what about making locks private and getting them in class B by public getters from class A?

Comment: That's slightly better, but it's still a good recipe for disaster. For example, two threds synchonizing on both locks but in a different order will lead to a deadlock. What **concrete** problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm writing simple application inspired by Netflix, I have clients, films, distributors and Main class is something like storage of available films and distributors that have contracts and clients that pay subscription etc. And it works like simulation, I mean, my clients are created automatically in Main functions and they automatically buy products. The problem is with buy() method in Client class. If I want my client to buy random stuff I have to block any change in ArrayList that stores products in Main (to avoid buying products that have been deleted in the same time).

Comment: The why would you need two locks? You just need a single lock guarding your collection of products.

Comment: Okay, I have collections of products and collections of clients and another one of distributors. And except that I have my account in Main as company. I can do some operations on account and on products in parallel, I think.

Comment: Go back to my first comment. If you really want separate locks, then encapsulate Don't let every caller be responsible for proper locking. Put that in a single class.

Comment: Okay, thank you for good advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole construct should be redesigned.

A class should encapsulate as much of its internals as possible. In an ideal world, no other class should see the fields or have to know when and what to synchronize/lock. A class should expose meaningful methods that answer questions regarding this instance or modify this instance's state from one valid state to another.

The concept of a "valid state" is domain-dependent, but typically involves combinations of field values, e.g. a (simplified) street crossing should not have all four traffic lights being green. If such a situation arises temporarily inside a state-changing method, it must not get visible to the outside world.

And using the `synchronized` keyword is one (traditional) way to achieve that. You'd declare `synchronized` the state-changer as well as all methods that might be affected by an invalid state.

You only need multiple lock objects for a single instance if the state decomposes into multiple independent parts, parts that can be changed without affecting one another. But then, if the field groups are so loosely coupled, why did you model this as one big instance instead of a bunch of smaller ones?

One more point: If you allow other classes to modify fields that are critical for the instance's validity, you completely break any encapsulation. Then you're no longer doing object-oriented programming, but treat instances as structures like in PASCAL in the 1970s and 1980s.

Have a look at thread-safe classes from the Java library, e.g. `java.util.Vector`. This class follows the simple pattern to allow only one thread at a time to access critical code, by just declaring some basic methods `synchronized`, i.e. using the instance itself as the lock object.

Answer (score 0):

A more common way would be to instantiate a ReadWriteLock and spawn two writelocks from it and use those in both A and B. And the same instance of A would share same locks